# Unexpected bindings reset on BizTalk 2009

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

I use many application on BizTalk 2009. I have noticed many times that, after a resource add (.dll) in a random application, all the bindings (custom pipelines) of a precise application totally reset to an early previous state.

I'm really curious of why this happens. But I also need a solution to stop that behavior or resolve automatically this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because it tries to apply a cached binding after you have deployed.  Sometimes it doesn't correctly update the cached binding and so a stale copy is used.  As per below, clearing these cached copies out helps in the short term, but often it comes back.

From [BizTalk Server: List of Errors and Warnings, Causes, and Solutions](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7204.biztalk-server-list-of-errors-and-warnings-causes-and-solutions.aspx)

> Visual Studio uses cached binding files when deploying BizTalk applications.  Removing these cached binding files will result in a ‘clean’ deployment that should resolve any binding related deployment errors.  The files are stored in %APPDATA%\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\Deployment\BindingFiles. Clearing the contents of this directory should resolve any deployment issues related to cached bindings.

See also [Import MSI change port pipelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38568500/import-msi-change-port-pipelines)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is frustrating and intermittent problem with BizTalk Sever 2009 and 2010.  I don't think there every was a guaranteed resolution, sorry.

However, you should not experience this if you are deploying your apps as complete packages using BTDF or just .msi+Bindings.

Comment: It can even occur with a .msi that doesn't have bindings it them.  So good practice is to always have bindings as part of your deployment.

Comment: Good point.  I consider a Binding file implicit in an .msi deployment.  Added for clarity. @Dijkgraaf