# BizTalk Send port rolling back changes

Tags: configuration, biztalk, rollback, biztalk-2013r2

I have a TEST BizTalk 2013 R2 environment.  It's paired with SQL Server 2014 and Windows Server 2012 R2.  It's a mirror of our production environment which has been stable and without issue for over 6 years.

I'm working on adding a new integration partner, and I've created some static send ports that utilize a custom send pipeline component that has been used reliably in production for the past 6 years as well.  The custom send pipeline adds archiving capability to EdiSend.

The problem is I've gone into the static send port and set the Send Pipeline several times now.  It will work for an unknown amount of time, but for some reason it keeps reverting back to EdiSend. I find this out when I go to look for the archived files.  The other oddity I've noticed is that if I go into Resource > Modify > Refresh, instead of opening up a File Select window in the directory last used, it will open up to the BizTalk install directory.  My first thought is something in the database must be rolling changes back?

Note, I'm the only one working on the test environment.  Has anyone else seen this before?  I'm wondering if a recent Windows Update is the culprit, as this started pretty recently.

[image]

Comment: No. There are no automatic updates being done to the test server.  However, I might have resolved the problem  First, I want to note what didn't work. I deleted the ports in question, and reimported the binding config xml.  What I believe fixed the issue is changing the SQL backup schedule on "Backup BizTalk Server (BizTalkMgmtDb)" from every 15 minutes to nightly at midnight. I'm curious to understand the correlation between the backup and the problem I was experiencing.

Comment: Strange, there shouldn't be any correlation between the two

Comment: agree. I wouldn't think there would be either.  that's why I only speculate that's what solved the problem.

Comment: So, I was wrong about back up being the culprit.  The Send Pipeline reverted back to EdiSend immediately after doing a modify => refresh => map.dll file.  So, I'm not sure why updating the maps is causing the send pipeline to change.  That's not making any sense either.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the files out of  %APPDATA%\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\Deployment\BindingFiles\     There is a known issue regarding it using a cached binding file in certain circumstances, which is why I asked about you doing a deploy, refreshing a DLL could trigger that

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected bindings reset on BizTalk 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762476/unexpected-bindings-reset-on-biztalk-2009)

Comment: Thank you. Cleaned out the files in the folder, did a DLL refresh, and the Send Pipeline binding didn't change.

Comment: So yes, duplicate of that other issue I linked.  As you can see, it has been around for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Clear the files out of `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\BizTalk Server\Deployment\BindingFiles\`

There is a known issue regarding it using a cached binding file in certain circumstances when deploying which has been around since as least [BizTalk 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42762476/unexpected-bindings-reset-on-biztalk-2009)